# Send SIGINT in python to os.system

Tags: python, linux, os.system

I am trying to run a Linux command `strace -c ./client` in python with `os.system()`. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> I get some output on the terminal. I have to send the "Process correctly halted" signal programmatically after one minute and want the terminal output that is produced after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in a file.
A pseudo script will be really helpful. If I use `subprocess.Popen` and then send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> signal from keyboard I didn't get output on the terminal,so have to use `os.system`

Answer (score 11):

In Python, you could programatically send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> signal using [`os.kill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill). Problem is, you need the `pid` of the process that'll receive the signal, and `os.system` does not tell you anything about that. You should use `subprocess` for that. I don't quite get what you said about not getting the output on the terminal.

Anyways, here's how you could do it:

```
import subprocess
import signal
import os

devnull = open('/dev/null', 'w')
p = subprocess.Popen(["./main"], stdout=devnull, shell=False)

# Get the process id
pid = p.pid
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)

if not p.poll():
    print("Process correctly halted")
```

Comment: I think your last line, if not p.poll(), might be wrong. poll() returns None if the process is still running, not None is True, so you print the message if the process is still running, not if it has stopped.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend subprocess python module for running linux commands. In that, SIGINT signal (equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> keyboard interrupt) can be sent programmatically to a command using `Popen.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` function. `Popen.communicate()` function will give you output. For example

```
import subprocess
import signal

..
process = subprocess.Popen(..)  # pass cmd and args to the function
..
process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)  # send Ctrl-C signal
..
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()  # get command output and error
..
```

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04 x64, if  I run python 2.7.6, I get an attribute error (popen object has no attribute send_signal). What's up with that?

Comment: It should be `process.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)`, signal.SIGINT raise `ValueError: Unsupported signal: 2`.

Comment: @RonenNess `CTRL_C_EVENT` is Windows, `SIGINT` is Linux. The question is tagged with Linux, so the answer is correct.