# Controlling buffer size for webcam video capture to file using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

In a Python script I want to capture a webcam stream and save it to a video file on local harddisk, but I want to script to determine lifecycle of the video. For this I am using `python-ffmpeg` library which is essentially a simple Python SDK around ffmpeg in a subprocess.

This is my snipped currently:

```py
from time import sleep
import ffmpeg


APPLICATION = "ffmpeg.exe"
CAMERA_NAME = "Sandberg USB Webcam Pro"

stream = ffmpeg.input(f"video={CAMERA_NAME}", format="dshow")
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, "output.mkv", preset="medium", c="copy")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = ffmpeg.run_async(stream, cmd=APPLICATION, overwrite_output=True, quiet=True)
    _ = input("Press enter when finished.")
    print("Shutting down in 3 seconds..")
    sleep(3)
    process.terminate()
```

This works fine. However, the process.terminate() is quite abrupt, since it essentially just kills the subprocess immediately. I've seen that this tends to cut off a few seconds of the video stream. I assume it is being written continuously and when killed whatever is already written remains.

Right now I have no control over the duration (of the.. buffer?). I'm just guessing it's around 3 seconds, hence my sleep call. Is there a way to configure this to ffmpeg?

Comment: How about monitor `-progress` file? You can check out how I implemented it in [my package](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio), [`ffmpegprocess.py`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio/blob/main/src/ffmpegio/ffmpegprocess.py) to be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to control the buffer size, we have to close FFmpeg gracefully.

For closing FFmpeg gracefully, we may write `'q'` to `stdin` pipe, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276793/output-always-corrupt-from-ffmpeg-using-selenium-python).

When we start recording, the following message appears: `Press [q] to stop, [?] for help`.
Writing `'q'` to `stdin` simulates pressing the `q` key.

---

- Open FFmpeg sub-process with `pipe_stdin=True`:

  ```
   process = ffmpeg.run_async(stream, cmd=APPLICATION, pipe_stdin=True, overwrite_output=True, quiet=True)
  ```
- Write `'q'` letter (with `encode("GBK")`) to `stdin` pipe, and "`communicate()`":

  ```
   process.stdin.write('q'.encode("GBK"))
   process.communicate()
  ```
- Wait for FFmpeg sub-process to end:

  ```
   process.wait()
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
from time import sleep
import ffmpeg
import signal

APPLICATION = "ffmpeg.exe"
CAMERA_NAME = "Sandberg USB Webcam Pro"

stream = ffmpeg.input(f"video={CAMERA_NAME}", format="dshow")   
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, "output.mkv", preset="medium", c="copy")

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    process = ffmpeg.run_async(stream, cmd=APPLICATION, pipe_stdin=True, overwrite_output=True, quiet=True)
    _ = input("Press enter when finished.")
    #sleep(10) # Record 10 seconds for testing
    process.stdin.write('q'.encode("GBK"))
    process.communicate()
    process.wait()
```

When I used `sleep(10)` instead of `_ = input`, the recorded video duration was about 9 seconds.
I think it records 9 seconds and not 10 seconds because it takes FFmpeg about one second to be loaded and start execution.

---

Setting real-time buffer to `100M`, and `fflags="nobuffer"` had no effect.

`rtbufsize="100M"`:

```
stream = ffmpeg.input(f"video={CAMERA_NAME}", rtbufsize="100M", format="dshow")
```

`fflags="nobuffer":`

```
stream = ffmpeg.input(f"video={CAMERA_NAME}", fflags="nobuffer", format="dshow")
```

It looks like FFmpeg flushes the buffers when we write `'q'`, there is no data loss and the buffer size has no effect.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Works like a charm!